# What is the difference between Local and Global Gauss Theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying Differential geometry. I don't fully understand the difference between the local and global Gauss-Bonnet theorem, or rather, I don't fully understand what the local GB theorem states.

The Local GB is given by:

$$\oint_\gamma \kappa_g ds = 2 \pi - \iint_{\text{int}(\gamma)} KdA $$

where $S$ is the surface and $\gamma(s)$ is a unit-speed simple closed curve on a surface patch $\sigma$. $\gamma$ is also assumed to be positively-oriented, $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$, $K$ is the gaussian curvature, and $dA$ is the area element of $\sigma$.

As I've understood, the global GB states that for compact surfaces, the Gaussian curvature remains invariant between two isomorphic surfaces (because the euler characteristic is invariant).

The Global GB is given by:

$$\iint_S K dA = 2\pi \chi(S)$$

Could someone explain it to me in simple terms, what the difference between the two theorems are, and specifically, what the local GB theorem states.

Thank you!

Comment: You said "Two *isomorphic* surfaces", I would rather say two *homeomorphic* surfaces. Also is not the Gaussian curvature but the integral of it that is a topological invariant.
The local version is called local because one has in mind domains which are geodesic triangles and these can be used to produce a basis of the topology.
The global version instead is applied to a compact surface without boundary and can be proved using the local version by considering a suitable triangulation of the surface.

Comment: Ah, yes of course it's the intagral of the Gaussian curvature. Does it then maybe make sense to say that the global curvature is invariant? 
Considering the local GB, isn't what you're saying in terms of \gamma being a curvelinear polygon? or maybe there is not much difference? Also I did not fully understand the statement...

Comment: The local Gauss-Bonnet theorem holds on a compact surface with boundary. In particular, it can be applied to a surface parameterized by a rectangle or disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The global Gauss-Bonnet is for a compact surface *without* boundary. It is proved by decomposing the surface into pieces, each of which is a surface with boundary, and applying the local Gauss-Bonnet theorem to each piece.

Comment: So can one say that the local Gauss-Bonnet says somthing about the curvature locally, while the global Gauss-Bonnat says something about the global curvature? or am I way off track? Also, because it is bounded that is why we use the integral of the geodesic curvature?

Comment: The local Gauss-Bonnet formula you've given holds on a surface with boundary that is *homeomorphic to a closed disk*. (That is, the interior of $\gamma\subset S$ is a disk with nice boundary.) You referred to $S$ and $\sigma$ but were quite sloppy in the statement. (If you want another source to read about this, download my free differential geometry text, linked in my profile.)